# How to force `geom_line()` to NOT use the shortest distance to connect points?

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2, line

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

`geom_line()` connects the dot with a single straight line, that is the shortest path between the two dots. I would like the line to go straight on the horizontal (or vertical) direction first and then goes up or down (or right) to connect the point that follows.

It sounds likely that this option is not already integrated in `ggplot2`. One way to do that would be to create a whole set of points that won't be displayed when `geom_point()` but that would be positioned at the same x position as the point that follows (or the same x position as the point the preceeds) and at the same y position as the point that precedes (or the same y position as the point that follows). It sounds like a complicated solution! And I don't really manage to make it work. Is there a better solution? In any case, can you help making a handy function that will do the two tricks (1.first vertical and 2.first horiozontal)?

Comment: Oh god! Yes exactly! Oh well that was easy. Can you make an answer out of your comment? Thank you Henrik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [**`geom_step`**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_step.html): "Connect observations by stairs"

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_step() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Should be called `geom_etch_a_sketch`